# Como fazer um alerta no browser, usando node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, alert

Sou **iniciante** em **node.js**, sei que a função principal do node não é essa, porém quero aprender um pouco mais sobre tal evento, outra duvida que também tenho é se posso usar **funções javascript comuns** no "meio" do meu código node.
Gostaria de uma maneira de adicionar o meu javascript **sem a função *fs.readFile()***
Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você usar o **ajax** você pode fazer assim:

No **lado servidor**

```
 res.send(500,'Errooooou')
```

e no **lado cliente**

```
error: function(error){
      if(error.responseText == 'Errooooou')
          alert("Sua resposta está errada.")
```